# How to add a row at a particular index in titanium

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a table in titanium, and I have added 3 rows. In one scenario I have removed a 2nd row from the table `table.deleteRow(index)` and after some process I need to add a row at that index.

Can any one please let me know how to add a row at a particular index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

`insertRowAfter` : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-insertRowAfter

or
`insertRowBefore` : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-insertRowBefore to do this

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that I have tried and the output is visible in the screenshot.

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var tableData = [ {title: 'Apples'}, {title: 'Bananas'}, {title: 'Carrots'}, {title: 'Potatoes'} ];

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
  data: tableData
});
win.add(table);
win.open();

table .insertRowAfter(3,{title: 'Inserted After'});
table .insertRowBefore(0,{title: 'Inserted Before'});
```

[image: Screenshot]